# Increasing results candidates for helm-ag?

Tags: helm, helm-ag

When I need to make bulk edits in my project, I use `helm-ag` to find my pattern recursively in all the files, run `replace-regexp` on the editing buffer, and then commit. One thing in particular I find very convenient about using this method is that unlike other methods, it doesn't open a buffer for each file and saves it, but applies changes directly to the file itself.

This worked very well, until my project became vast and refactoring things results because much harder because `helm-ag` can only match up to 9999 candidates:

[image]

I found no variable which controls the maximum amount of matches, and doing `(setq helm-ag-base-command "ag --vimgrep --max-count 999999")` didn't seem to change anything either.

Any way I can increase the candidate count? Alternatively, without resorting to shell commands or installing new system binaries, is there any way to achieve what I want without the use of `ag`? I can guarantee the existence of `ag` on the system, but not any alternative searches.

Comment: https://github.com/emacsorphanage/helm-ag/blob/master/helm-ag.el#L523